# How to pass hash method rspec to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, hash, rspec

Using  Rails 5.1.4, Ruby 2.4.1, rspec

Scenario:

In article destroy allow only user current_ma_user with role "a,m"

Then:

Check if current_ma_user.role = "a,m"
   or current_ma_user own article (@article.user)

So I create current_ma_user as hash as well as user.
Then call role to check what is user[role ]

Problems:

1. How to add new method to hash.
2. How to pass that hash.method from rspec controller_spec to controller.

Failures:

```
  1) ArticlesController DELETE #destroy destroys the requested article
     Failure/Error: delete :destroy, params: {id: article.to_param}, session: valid_session, :current_ma_user.role => "a,m"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `role' for :current_ma_user:Symbol
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:172:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:171:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the [gist](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/kul1/c5bb17955ec133243597a40ce4e92198.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

articles_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do

    class Hash #patch to temp pass problem 1
      def role
        "a,m"  #Hard Code, need to call user["role"] need code
      end
    end

    user = {}
    user["uid"] = "admin"
    user["provider"] = "Facebook"
    user["email"] = "1.0@kul.asia"
    user["role"] = "a,m"

    current_ma_user = user

  describe "DELETE #destroy" do

    it "destroys the requested article" do
      article = Article.create! valid_attributes
      expect {
        delete :destroy, params: {id: article.to_param}, session: valid_session
      }.to change(Article, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "redirects to the articles list" do
      article = Article.create! valid_attributes
      delete :destroy, params: {id: article.to_param}, session: valid_session
      expect(response).to redirect_to(articles_url)
    end
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController   before_action :load_article, only: [:show, :destroy]

  def destroy
    if current_ma_user.role.upcase.split(',').include?("A") || current_ma_user == @article.user
    #if current_ma_user == @article.user
      @article.destroy
    end
      redirect_to :action=>'index'   end

  private

  def load_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])   end

end
```

Updated with line number:
[image]

Updated debug to show value of current_ma_user in .spec and controller
[image: in spec]

[image: in controller]

Comment: are you using a factory to create the articles? If so please post

Comment: No, I tried to  create user and current_ma_user for destroy, the other test like create, update are ok

Comment: Can you show `# ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:172:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'` - this string (and another around this)

Comment: @kunashir Pls see if the updated with line is enough or any info might help. Thanks

Comment: It seems like your `current_ma_user` in some place was defined like `Symbol` but you try to use it like object and call `role`. Try to analyze your backtrack for this error. May you make a gist with full trace and full code of controller

Comment: @kunashir, I posted wrong comment in controller and now updated with the error. In controller expected current_ma_user.role to be "a,m" ,What I found relevant is line articles_controller_spec.rb line 172. I tried force defined method in current_ma_user hash and verified debugger confirmed the role will return "a,m" in .spec.rb but when check in controller.rb

Comment: @kunashir I just added gist in question Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where your error is coming from (in your controller):

`if current_ma_user.role.upcase.split(',').include?("A") || current_ma_user == @article.user`

### Suggested Solutions

- *Where is current_ma_user defined in the controller?* (if it’s not assigned, then it needs to be assigned *before* you call the role method on the current_ma_user variable.

Try that and see how it goes.

- Do something like this:

`current_ma_user = User.find( params[:user_id])`

- Now you seem to want to pass something into the params hash. Remember to white list whatever you decide to pass into params. Whether it is user id or roles id etc, or a roles string.
- When writing your tests, pass in the approrpiate values to the params hash. If you are passing in a `user_id` in your test, then you will have to make sure that a user is created in the test.

`delete :destroy, {:id => article.id.to_s, :user_id =>  @current_ma_user.id  }, session: valid_session`

- also perhaps in your spec file, in your test, put the current_ma_user in a before filter and make it an instance variable so it will be accessible to all your tests:

  `before(:each) do
        @current_ma_user = user.create( <--- create the user with the 
        appropriate attributes here --->)
  end`

### Warning: Untested

I just typed it into the stack overflow editor.

Comment: I already added which result in debugger image. I just don't know how to pass the current_ma_user.role to controller to use it.

Comment: In the test, pass the role through params hash but you'll have to whitelisr it (don't forget) but even when you do that you still have to assign the current_ma_user and you must still define the role method on it. Try the above as a sanity check first then try passing the role through params

Comment: How to whitelist or passing the role through params. I now use a global var like this     $xvars["current_ma_user"] = current_ma_user
in spec file and retrieve it later in controller: using   
      current_ma_user = $xvars["current_ma_user"] then call current_ma_user.role and worked as expected. But like to know to use params instead of another global var for better.

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters try this link.  Also do you have a column for "role" in the users table?

Comment: Yes, I have user["role"] = "a,m"

Comment: yes but where are you setting the `current_ma_user` in your controller? you need a line like this: `current_ma_user = User.find( params[:user_id])`.

Comment: and in your test you need to pass the user id to the params hash.

Comment: OK Here what I understand: the test file articles_controller_spec.rb need it's own data to work with controller. But in the real rails run those data like: current_ma_user, User are from it's source eg User from model and curren_ma_user from controller. However we pass the test data which need to have it (from made it up eg Factory) and pass through params as need but not all. Because in real dev or production not all data from params. That is my problem. So I only need params :id not current_ma_user and I can pass it through my other global hash to work in controller. Thanks

Comment: "Because in real dev or production not all data from params." where are you getting the curren_ma_user in the real production environment? ---> what is the answer to this question?

Comment: (In Controller) def current_ma_user @user ||= User.where(:auth_token => cookies[:auth_token]).first if cookies[:auth_token] end

Comment: ok so in your test you will need to: (i) create a user and (ii) ensure that the the user's authentication token is set in the cookies hash